# Having trouble with showing another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently trying to input another listview in my contentView file to test if it'll show, but for some reason it isn't showing the list. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why this is happening as I am not receiving any error message.
This is the code for the list file

```
import SwiftUI

extension Image{
    
    func anotherImgModifier() -> some View{
        self
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame( width: 75, height: 75)
            .cornerRadius(9)
    }
}

struct PokeListView: View {
    @State var imgURL: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var pokeWebService: PokeWebService
    //functions
    
//    func loadImage() async -> [Image]{
//        for 
//    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List( pokeWebService.pokeList?.results ?? [], id: \.id){ pokemon in
                NavigationLink(destination: PokeDetailsView(urlString: pokemon.url, counter: 4, name: pokemon.name)) {
                    AsyncImage(url:URL(string: "https://play.pokemonshowdown.com/sprites/bw/\(pokemon.name).png")){ image in
                        image.anotherImgModifier()
                                }
                    placeholder: {
                                    Image(systemName: "photo.circle.fill").iconModifer()
                                }.padding(40)
                    Text(pokemon.name.uppercased()).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .task{
                            do{
                                try await pokeWebService.getPokemonFromPokemonList(from: pokemon.url)
                            } catch{
                                print("---> task error: \(error)")
                            }
                            
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            do{
                try await pokeWebService.getPokemonList()
            } catch{
                print("---> task error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PokeListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PokeListView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
            .padding()
            .environmentObject(PokeWebService())
    }
}
```

This is the code for the ContentView where I was trying to input the list file.
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var newsWebService = NewsWebService()
    @StateObject var pokeWebService = PokeWebService()
    let gbImg = Image("pokeball").resizable()
    @State private var gridLayout: [GridItem] = [ GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    
    @State private var  gridColumn: Int = 2
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15, content: {
                    Spacer()
                    NewsCapsule()
                    //GRID
                    
                
                        //BERRIES, POKEMON, GAMES
                    GroupBox(label: Label{
                        Text("PokéStuff")
                    } icon: {
                        Image("pokeball").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                             , content: {
                        PokeListView()
                    }).padding(.horizontal, 20).foregroundColor(.red)
                    
                })//:VSTACK
                
            })//:SCROLLVIEW
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Pokemon",displayMode: .large)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing, content: {
                    Image(systemName: "moon.circle")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                })
            })
            
        }//:NAVIGATIONBAR
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(NewsWebService())
            .environmentObject(PokeWebService())

    }
}
```

How would I get to fix this?

Comment: Your content view contains a scroll view. That scroll view wraps the list view (which contains its own scroll view) Also, you have multiple navigation views (you really only need the one in content view) I would recommend making the scroll view a list instead, then making the pokelist a `Section` that has a `ForEach` instead of a list. 

This should help I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT-1:

with further tests, this is what worked for me:

in `ContentView`, add `.frame(height: 666)` to the `VStack {...}`.
This is the reason why you do not see anything. You need a frame height.

Also  in `ContentView`, add `.environmentObject(pokeWebService)` to the `NavigationView`,
and just use `PokeListView()`. This is to pass the `pokeWebService`
to that view. After that, all works for me. You may want to experiment
with different frame sizes and such likes. You should also remove the `NavigationView` from your `PokeListView`, there is no need for it.

Comment: I tried that, but it still isn't showing up

Comment: Its weird, it works on the individual views but not the content view. I tried using a navigation link, but that did not work as well

Comment: updated my answer with more info.